# Karate POST request returned Invalid content type message for REST POST transaction

Tags: karate

Given url 'https://api-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/'

- And header Authorization = 'Bearer '+ token
- And header X-XSRF-header = 'xxxxxxxxx'
- And header Content-Type = 'application/xxx.pingixxxxxx.checkUsernamePassword+json'

// in the above line "checkUsernamePassword" automatically changes to (lower case u & p) "checkusernamepassword" during request process in Karate.

// i.e it changes to 'application/xxx.pingixxxxx.checkusernamepassword+json' during POST request

And request { Username: '12345xxx', Password:'12233xxx'}

When method post

Karate response is { "code": "INVALID_CONTENT_TYPE" "message": Invalid content type xxxxx}

Case 1: I reproduced same error response with Postman when I used u & p lowercase Content_Type = 'application/xxx.pingixxxxxxx.checkusernamepassword+json'

Case 2: I got valid response in Postman when I used U&P upper case Content_Type = 'application/xxx.pingixxxxxxx.checkUsernamePassword+json' in Postman.

Please clarify how I can force header Content-Type in Karate with upper case U & P or some other keyword can be used to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does look like there is an issue. We are working on the new version, it looks to be fixed, perhaps you can confirm as well: https://github.com/intuit/karate/commit/19d1fe0ab33728044902f5f3a2f7d27b881c898d

You can try switching to `karate-jersey` instead of `karate-apache`. If that does not work, help us by testing the upcoming version so that we can release it faster:  https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide